# Calling a procedure within a Trigger! DB2

Tags: sql, triggers, db2, procedure

Hello I have created both a procedure and a trigger, the objective of these two are to notify my dispatchers when they are using an asset that has a dead satellite. 
Here is my Procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DEAD_TRAILERS (
OUT oMSG_TYPE INTEGER, 
OUT oERROR_MSG VARCHAR(255)
)
LANGUAGE SQL
SPECIFIC SP_DEAD_TRAILERS
MAIN: BEGIN 
  --// 1 - warning message 
  SET oMSG_TYPE = 1; 
  SET oERROR_MSG = 'SAT ON TRAILER IS DEAD. PLEASE GET IT REPLACED';  
END
```

and here is my trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER DEAD_TRAILERS_NOTIFY
AFTER UPDATE OF TRAILER ON TRIP 
REFERENCING NEW AS N OLD AS O 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN ATOMIC

DECLARE DEAD_SAT VARCHAR(10); 
DECLARE MSG VARCHAR(70); 

SET DEAD_SAT = COALESCE((SELECT TRAILER_ID FROM TRAILER WHERE LAST_SAT_DATE < CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 8 DAYS AND N.TRAILER = TRAILER_ID),'OK');

    IF DEAD_SAT <> 'OK' AND USER NOT IN ('VISTAR','TM4WIN') THEN
    CALL DEAD_TRAILERS();  
    END IF;
END
```

When trying to execute my trigger I receive this error

```
-- [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/NT64] SQL0440N  
No authorized routine named "DEAD_TRAILERS" of type "PROCEDURE" 
having compatible arguments was found.  
LINE NUMBER=13.  SQLSTATE=42884
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have defined the procedure with two (output) parameters, but in the trigger you are calling some other procedure with no parameters.

Comment: As @mustaccio states, this is simply the error message when a procedure is not defined.  It has nothing to do with calling inside a trigger.  But also, it is not really clear how you expect this code to "notify [your] dispatchers", since the error message isn't going anywhere.  Could you explain the desired notification behavior?

Comment: Well I would like the queries to sent out a notifications whenever the asset they are trying to use meet the qualification of having a dead sat